# Is there a way to save my method for solving this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

$y' + y = y^{-2}$

I divided everything by $y^{-2}$ and let $v = y^3$, then solved as normal. (I relaced the $y^2$ with $y^{2}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{dv}{dy}$ after differentiating the $v$. Then I solved the "ordinary linear first-order differential equation". (Except I know technically its not). I know this was not correct because of the $y^2$ in front of $y'$ after division by $y^{-2}$ AND I know you can solve it the simple way by moving $y$ over...
What I am looking for is a fix for my method, if any exists.

After $v$ substitution, $\frac{1}{3}\frac{dv}{dx} + v = 1$

After integration, $ln|1-v| = 3x + c$

After raising both sides to $e$ and resubstitution, $|1-y^3|=e^c e^{3x}$

And that's the problem. $e^{3x}$, when it should be $e^{-3x}$

Comment: It would be clearer to write the calculations with $v$ (at least the ODE and the solution obtained if you don't want to detail all), so we can figure out where it went wrong.

Comment: I have added some detail. can you still pick up the mistake? i will add more at further request

Comment: The derivative of $\ln|1-v|$ is $\frac{-v'}{1-v}$, you need to include the inner derivative.

Comment: ok I see. How can I make that happen? You cannot multiply and divide by that, can you?

Answer (score 2):

$$y'+y=y^{-2} \implies y^2y'+y^3=1 \implies \frac{1}{3}(y^3)'+y^3=1$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}+3z=3 \implies \frac{de^{3x}z}{dx}=3 \implies e^{3x} z=3x+C.$$
Finally, $$z=3xe^{-3x}+Ce^{-3x}\implies y^3=3xe^{-3x}+Ce^{-3x}$$

Comment: The trick after the 2nd arrow is pretty clever and solves my problem. I will write up my solution more so perhaps you could see where **I** went wrong